# MDB for a remote queue with JBOSS EAP

Tags: java, queue, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I'm working with `Jboss EAP 6.2`, `Java 7` and `HornetQ` embedded in `Jboss`.
I want configure a MDB is listening on a remote queue. 
I configured the MDB with `ejb-jar.xml` file. I don't know set the remote queue hostname. I tried with property `hostname` and `connectionParameters`. This is my `ejb-jar.xml` snippet:

```
<enterprise-beans>

    ...

    <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>SMListenerMDB</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.service.queue.SMListenerMDB</ejb-class>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>reconnectAttempts</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>-1</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>queue/SmQueue</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>connectorClassName</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</activation-config-property-value>
          </activation-config-property>                
        </activation-config>
    </message-driven>       
</enterprise-beans>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved inserting the code:

```
    <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>connectionParameters</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>host=HOSTANME;port=5445</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
```